# Codename One get and disable all components and sub components

Tags: java, components, codenameone

I have an Android application with several containers and other components like buttons and labels.

The app  uses popups to inform the user on the first run about the usage of the app and its components.

I want to disable the form and/ or all the components and sub components inside, until the users presses the close button of the popup dialog.

I have tried using `form.setEnabled (false)`, but that didn't work.

```
form.getComponentCount ()
```

also only gets the containers and the toolbar and not what's inside the containers, so it is insufficient.

Now I use the following code to disable the components :

```
form.setScrollable (false); 

for (Component component : containerOne ) {
        component.setEnabled(false);
}

for (Component component : containerTwo ) {
        component.setEnabled(false);
}

for (Component component : containerThree ) {
        component.setEnabled(false);
}

buttonOne.setEnabled(false);
buttonTwo.setEnabled(false);

textFieldOne.setEnabled(false);
textFieldTwo.setEnabled(false);
```

but this takes a lot of code, since I need to enable the components later and I am also using several classes.

I there a one-liner or easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ComponentSelector](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/ComponentSelector.html) to enable/disable components in one line of code.

```
$("*", rootContainer).setEnabled(false)
```

1. The `$` is an alias of `ComponentSelector.select()`
2. The "*" is a selector (similar to a CSS selector) that says to match all components.
3. The `rootContainer` is a `Container` object that serves as the root to being selection on.
4. `setEnabled(false)` sets enabled=false on all Components in the found set.

Comment: Many thanks for posting this, Steve. I will only be able to have a look at this by the end of the week. Any doubts I get back to you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you use a Dialog as long as it shows nothing in the form is clickable.

If you want to further block anything disabling is problematic because it isn't recursive. Just override pointer pressed/released in `Form` and conditionally block them. They won't propagate the event onward and you can get the same effect without the problematic style change to disabled.

e.g.:

```java
class MyForm extends Form {
    private boolean blockFormEvents;
    // ...
   
    @Override
    public void pointerReleased(int x, int y) {
        if(blockFormEvents) return;
        super.pointerReleased(x, y);
    }
   
    @Override
    public void pointerReleased(int[] x, int[] y) {
        if(blockFormEvents) return;
        super.pointerReleased(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void pointerPressed(int x, int y) {
        if(blockFormEvents) return;
        super.pointerPressed(x, y);
    }
   
    @Override
    public void pointerPressed(int[] x, int[] y) {
        if(blockFormEvents) return;
        super.pointerPressed(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Shai, thanks for the input. I didn't see that changing the dialog type from Dialog to InteractionDialog would come with the "benefit" of losing ability to have the components blocked by default. How do I override the form? Like in : form @override public void pointerReleased?

Comment: It's more in `pointerRelease`. `InteractionDialog` doesn't block the form. `Dialog` does. That's the core difference between them.

Comment: I don't know how to do that with code. Could you provide a snippet?

Comment: Added a sample.